# Animate the change to 'disabled' state using in jQuery (or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

**Question**

Is it possible to **animate** the change to and from an input's disabled state using jQuery (or some other Javascript library)

**Details**

Have different CSS styles for a regular input and one that is disabled. When changing between the different states, would like the user to see the previous state fade into the new state.

Is it possible to animate this change just by changing 'disabled' state of the input? Perhaps by doing something like this:

```
// CSS
input{
   background-color: white;
}  
input:disabled{
   background-color: grey;
}

// Javascript
$.find('input').animate({'disabled': false});
```

Or will I need to change the disabled state of the input, and then animate the input styling change separately?

```
// Javascript
$.find('input').prop('disabled', false);
$.find('input').animate({'background-color': 'white'});
```

Comment: It will be better to animate the opacity or other i.e background-color property when changing the state from normal to disabled and in animate callback you can change the property to disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with CSS transitions and the `:disabled` pseudo-class

```js
$("#handler").change(function(){

  $("#myInput").prop("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
  
});
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: background 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: background 1s ease;
 -o-transition: background 1s ease;
 -ms-transition: background 1s ease;
 transition: background 1s ease;
}

input:disabled {
 background: #666666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="handler" />

<br />

<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```